# Vue calling axios upon every select box selection

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I currently have a vue template that is calling a method(axios call) upon page load and it works properly, however, I'm trying to modify this so that any time I select an option from the select box it will re-call the axios call method with the selected option. Basically, using this example, I'm wondering how I could send the seleced value of 1,2, or 3 into the fetchItems method as `data = {value}` and make the axios call upon that selection:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <label>Choose Item Type</label>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="itemTypes" id="itemTypes">
        <option v-for="itemTypeOption in itemTypeOptions" v-bind:value="itemTypeOption.value">{{ itemTypeOption.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>

export default{
  data() {
    return: {
      itemTypes: [],
      itemTypeOptions: [
        {value:1, name:"A"},
        {value:2, name:"B"},
        {value:3, name:"All"}
      ]
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchItems();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchItems() {
      axios.get('/report/items/data')
      .then(response => {        
        this.rows = response.data
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by @change event -

```
    <template>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <label>Choose Item Type</label>
        <select class="form-control"
                v-model="itemTypes"
                id="itemTypes"
                @change="handleSelect">
            <option v-for="itemTypeOption in itemTypeOptions"
                    v-bind:value="itemTypeOption.value">{{ itemTypeOption.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
          itemTypes: {},
          itemTypeOptions: [
            {value:1, name:"A"},
            {value:2, name:"B"},
            {value:3, name:"All"}
          ]
        }
      },
      created() {
        this.fetchItems();
      },
      methods: {
        fetchItems(value = '') {
          axios.get('/report/items/data', {params: {data: value}})
          .then(response => {        
            this.rows = response.data
          })
        },
        handleSelect() {
            this.fetchItems(itemTypes.value);
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways. An easy one is to add `@input="someMethod()"` or `@change="someMethod()"` to your select. You can even use `$event.target.value` to ge to the value directly.

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="itemTypes" id="itemTypes">
  <option v-for="itemTypeOption in itemTypeOptions" v-bind:value="itemTypeOption.value" @input="fetchItems($event.target.value)">{{ itemTypeOption.name }}</option>
</select>
```

and in fetchItems

```
fetchItems(val = '') {
  axios.get('/report/items/' + val)
  .then(response => {        
    this.rows = response.data
  })
}
```